# Update search help for intags:mine to replace "favorite" with "watched"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center, tag-watching

The [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for `intags:mine` still refers to "favorite" tags on Stack Overflow.  This is outdated since "favorites" were replaced by "Watched Tags".  This is how the help is worded:

> `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as
> favorite.

Please update the help documentation to mention "Watched" tags, as is done in the [Meta Stack Exchange search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: This is bizarre, since they updated the line before that to refer to saves, which was a far more recent change.

Comment: @Laurel: It's because this was an edit I made to the MSE search help page after that update, not realizing that SO had a customized version of the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made this change to the network-wide version of this Help Center page on MSE back in October, but forgot that SO had a site-specific override of this Help Center page. I've now updated the relevant portions of the corresponding Help Center page on SO to match.

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: @toolic: Since it was just a copy and paste from MSE, it was a pretty straightforward change :)